# SublimeText Salesforce IDE Plugin

Tags: ide, sublime

Is anyone familiar with the [Salesforce IDE plugin](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Salesforce%20IDE) for SublimeText? I have installed it, added my login_url, username and password but it says

> Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.

. I have even reset my security token and then inserted that too but I'm having no luck getting it to work.

**Edit:**
Project settings:

```
{
    "projects":
    {
        "sandbox":
        {
            "default": true,
            "login_url": "https://test.salesforce.com",
            "password": "password",
            "security_token": "abcdefghijk123456789",
            "username": "myusername@email.com"
        }
    }
}
```

**2nd Edit:**
Says login succesful in the status bar now when switching project, but I cannot see any of my pages, triggers or classes.

**3rd Edit:**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sandbox is the default project now.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

reloading Packages/User/toolingapi.sublime-settings

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Login Succeed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sandbox is the default project now.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Login Succeed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

reloading Packages/User/toolingapi.sublime-settings
reloading Packages/User/component_metadata.sublime-settings

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sObjects Cache are saved to Local
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

reloading Packages/User/sobjects_completion.sublime-settings
reloading Packages/User/symbol_table.sublime-settings

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sandbox is the default project now.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Login Succeed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

reloading Packages/User/toolingapi.sublime-settings
```

Comment: The mavensmate plugin right ? (Not sure if there are any others). Please specify this in your question/title.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke Not that one, theres a new plugin: https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Salesforce%20IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know, I am in china behind the GFW, I can't see the Human Beings Verification alert, so I need to use VPN to answer your question, sorry about that.

You need to click new > new project to download the apex code, switch project just switch but not create project.

Comment: I appreciate your effort despite being behind GTW. Well it looks like its doing something, just not sure how long it should take... Its been on the `[2014.09.11 14:51:33] [sf:retrieve] Start to download package zipFile` in the terminal for more than 4 minutes now. How long does this usually take?

Comment: @Imran, usually 23 seconds even if the org is very complex project.

Comment: It seems to have completed however I do not see anything in the folder named `projectname-20140911`. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: @Imran, can you check your console log by opening it by press ``ctrl+```?

Comment: please check the output in my original question.

Comment: @Imran, you need to click ``Project > Refresh Folders`` in the menu item,  The project is generated but not shown in the sidebar, there has problem in windows here caused by latest release, OSX is ok.

Comment: Ah yes this refresh the files and I can now see the files. Do I need to upload changes back to the server again? When I press save in some of my pages after making changes I do not see this reflected on Salesforce.

Comment: @Imran, you can click right button in the code file, you will see the Sublime Apex context menu, you can see the commands to process the code. There have some commands in main menu, sidebar menu and context menu of this plugin.

There are many other features in the plugin, maybe you need to check the [README.MD](https://github.com/xjsender/SublimeApex) for this plugin.

Because of the GFW, I may not be always stay here, you can reach me in github directly or just wait my reply for some time at here.

Comment: @Imran, the problem just happened has been fixed, you can check that by upgrading your plugin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17081/discussion-between-imran-and-hao-liu).